# How do you open, view, and edit .jar class files in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, jar

I would like to change the background color of a few `.class` files in the `jar`.

When I try to open it in eclipse it says the `.jar` file has no attachment.

I'm still a newbie and just trying to learn more about **Android programming**.

Comment: What is the background color of a class file?

Comment: I guess I mean java file...Programmatic as opposed to XML

Comment: Where does the .jar file com from? What kind of library is it?

Comment: It's the PayPalAndroidSDK.jar. It's in my referenced Libraries file. Not sure what you mean by what kind..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the title you write that you want to open a .jar file but in the content you write you want to change the background color so that I am a little confused.

If you wanna to open a .jar file, the tool "jd-gui" may help and you can get it here: http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui

Comment: Yes, this is what I wanted. Thank You. I'm not sure I'll be successful editing the files but at least you pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: link no longer works: Erreur 403 - Refus de traitement de la requête (Interdit - Forbidden)